# How can I find the size of `map` in ocaml? I am using `Map.Make` functor to create module?

Tags: ocaml

I could not find any `size` or `len` function in the official documentation. What is a simple way to find the number of elements in a map created using:

`module M = Map.Make(String)`

I am looking for something like `M.size M.empty : 0`.

Answer (score 8):

The function that you're looking for is called `cardinal` (as in the cardinality of a set).

Example:

```
module M = Map.Make(String)

let m = M.singleton "x" "y"
let () = Printf.printf "%d\n" (M.cardinal m)
```

This will print `1`, as there is exactly one binding.

Answer (score 0):

```
hoogle4ocaml ": 'a t -> int$" | grep -i map
```

Would tell you:

```
~/.opam/4.05.0/lib/ocaml/map.mli:    val cardinal: 'a t -> int
```

Cf. https://github.com/UnixJunkie/hoogle_for_ocaml

So, the short answer is:

```
Map.cadinal your_map
```

PS: and yes, the OCaml community is still dearly missing the equivalent of Hoogle in the Haskell community. There are some hacks around, like the one I just linked, but we would need a serious one, correctly working, actively maintained and largely vetted by the community